# SQL custom search function : unable to join two tables

Tags: php, jquery, search

```
  // grab the search types.
  $searchSQL = "SELECT  * FROM jsprofile WHERE ";

  $types = array();
  $types[] = isset($_GET['sicno'])?"`name` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['sname'])?"`icno` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB1}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['sgender'])?"`gender` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB2}%'":'';

  $types = array_filter($types, "removeEmpty"); // removes any item that was empty (not checked)

  if (count($types) < 1)
     $types[] = "`icno` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'"; // use the body as a default search if none are checked

      $andOr = isset($_GET['matchall'])?'AND':'AND';
  $searchSQL .= implode(" {$andOr} ", $types) . "  ORDER BY `icno`"; // order by title.

  $searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$searchSQL}");

//  if (mysql_num_rows($searchResult) < 1) {
  ///   $error[] = "The search term provided {$searchTerms} yielded no results.";
```

Everything works fine from this point. I am able to search... however when i tried to join two tables..

```
  // grab the search types.
  $searchSQL = "SELECT  * FROM jsprofile INNER JOIN medi WHERE ";

  $types = array();
  $types[] = isset($_GET['sicno'])?"`name` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['sname'])?"`icno` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB1}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['sgender'])?"`gender` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB2}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['medical'])?"`medical` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB2}%'":'';

  $types = array_filter($types, "removeEmpty"); // removes any item that was empty (not checked)

  if (count($types) < 1)
     $types[] = "`icno` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'"; // use the body as a default search if none are checked

      $andOr = isset($_GET['matchall'])?'AND':'AND';
  $searchSQL .= implode(" {$andOr} ", $types) . "  ORDER BY `icno`"; // order by title.

  $searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$searchSQL}");

//  if (mysql_num_rows($searchResult) < 1) {
  ///   $error[] = "The search term provided {$searchTerms} yielded no results.";
```

When I did this.. nothing seems to come out is there anything wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1):

you should check the MySQL JOIN syntax (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

you need to put an `ON` clause in there

this line:

```
$searchSQL = "SELECT  * FROM jsprofile INNER JOIN medi WHERE ";
```

should be something like this:

```
$searchSQL = "SELECT  * FROM jsprofile INNER JOIN medi On jsprofile.[key] = medi.[key] WHERE ";
```

obviously, substitute your key names into that query

Answer (score 1):

For starters:

```
$searchSQL = "SELECT  * FROM jsprofile INNER JOIN medi WHERE ";
```

...is only valid on MySQL, where an INNER JOIN lacking criteria to link the tables is interpreted as a CROSS JOIN -- producing a cartesian product.  That means it will produce rows, but there'll be every `medi` record related to each `jsprofile` table and vice versa.

As long as there are records based on the search criteria, the query will return results -- just not good ones.  So you'll have to explain "nothing comes out" for a helpful answer...

Second, using:

```
$searchSQL = "SELECT  * FROM jsprofile ... WHERE 1 = 1 ";
```

...will allow you to concatenate additional WHERE clauses, so long as they start with " AND ...":

```
$types[] = isset($_GET['sicno'])?" AND `name` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
```

...without needing the logic you've defined already.

Third, using a [Full Text Search (FTS)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) would be simpler and faster than using LIKE with wildcards on the left side, because the wildcard on the left side of a LIKE renders any index on the column unusable.  However, MySQL FTS requires that the table(s) searched be using the MyISAM engine - look to 3rd party tools like Sphinx to accomplish the same functionality.

```
WHERE MATCH(column1, column2) AGAINST ($searchTerm)
```